# JAVA- Jframe se oculta al abrir la aplicacion desde la barra de tareas mostrandome Jdialog con el fondo del esccritorio

Tags: java, jframe, jdialog

estoy desarrollando una aplicacion donde tengo un Jframe Padre y para realizar algunos registros utilizo nuevas ventanas en Jdialog.

cuando se esta trabajando en el jdialog en el fondo se ve el jframe padre y esto es correcto.
El problema esta cuando tengo el jdialog abierto y si el usuario abre cualquier otra aplicación ya sea navegador, juego, excel, etc, al volver a dar clic en la aplicación en la barra de tareas volvemos a la aplicacion mostrándome el Jdialog, pero no me muestra de fondo el Jframe padre, me muestra la aplicación que usaba antes y encima el jDialog.

aqui esta el claro ejemplo cuando estoy en la aplicacion e un jdialog y paso a cualquier otra aplicacion, cuando vuelvo al programa este me muesta el jdialgo pero no el jframe de fondo en este caso me muestra el navegador de fondo y no el jframe, aun si le quito la tranparencia para majearlo normal sigue igual ver imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en realidad al volvar al prgrama deveria verse asi con el jframe padre detras.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta es la forma como lo estoy llamando en estos momentos
jD_FrmNewRadicados frm1 = new jD_FrmNewRadicados(new FrmPrincipal(), true);
frm1.setVisible(true);

e utilizados varios tipos de llamarlo pero ninguno funciona
e utilizado
.pack()
e utilizado
jD_FrmNewRadicados frm1 = new jD_FrmNewRadicados (new javax.swing.JDialog(), true);
frm1 .setVisible(true);

e convertido los Jdialog en modales y nada funciona.

la unica que funciona es colocar el Jframe como jframe.SetOlwayOnTop(true);
pero esto no me permite usar otras aplicaciones en el PC a menos que le de Minimizar directamente a la ventana, o bien cierre los Jdialog abiertos y luego minimice el Jframe

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Tiene que ser visible tu esfuerzo, acá no hacemos deberes, por favor añade tu código, lee [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), además te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Esto puede ser problema de tu ordenador y no del programa, los diálogos se muestran en una ventana aparte de la aplicación original, cuando se muestra en la barra de tareas deberían aparecer las dos ventanas en el mismo ícono, como si estuviesen superpuestas. Tal vez se está mostrando un solo ícono el cual está ligado a la ventana de dialogo y no al jFrame

Comment: Acabe de actualizar el contenido de la pregunta, y mas para quien cree que me tiene que hacer los deberes.. no necesito que me haga ningun deber solo no encuentro la forma de que al volver a la aplicacion con el Jdialog activo muestre es el Jframe no el fondo X como en la imagen muestra el navegador de fondo.......... tambien realice los mismos ejercicios en otros PC iniciandolos como nuevos proyecyos pero muy basicos y secede lo mismo, para la persona que pregunto que podia ser el PC

Answer (score 0):

Encontre el problema, debido a que los botones los llamo desde un Jpanel externo al jframe estos no herendan la propiedad parent del jframe, y por mas que se declare un Jframe dentro de jpanel externo este no funciona..

aun no encuentro la solucion correcta pero para poder solucionarlo temporalmente me toco crear o trasladar todo lo del Jpanel externo dentro de otros componentes del jframe y realizar su llamado desde alli, para que tome la propiedad parent del jframe principal